# fastest way to sum results from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables like below. Now I need the sum of [Occures], for all records sharing the same [FirstName].

[image]

To do that we now use an union, followed by a group by function like below:

```
create table #foo(FirstName varchar(500), Occures int)
create table #bar(FirstName varchar(500), Occures int)
create table #fb(FirstName varchar(500), Occures int)
 insert into #foo values('a', 1)
 insert into #foo values('b', 2)
 insert into #foo values('c', 3)
 insert into #foo values('d', 4)
 insert into #bar values('c', 1)
 insert into #bar values('d', 2)
 insert into #bar values('g', 3)
 insert into #bar values('h', 4);

 insert into #fb
        select * from #foo 
  union select * from #bar
        select FirstName
             , sum(Occures) as Occures 
          from #fb 
      group by FirstName

drop table #foo
drop table #bar
drop table #fb
```

I need the following result:

[image]

Is there a neater way thinkable? I am trying to make this faster and since the current tables have lots of rows and good indexes, I was hoping for a solution where I join the current tables instead of pumping everything through a temp table or cte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you seem to want:

```
select name, sum(occures)
from ((select name, occures from #foo) union all
      (select name, occures from #bar)
     ) fb
group by name;
```

If I assume the following:

- There are no duplicate names in either table.
- You only want names that in both tables.

Then you can use `join`:

```
select f.name, (f.occures + b.occures) as occures
from #foo f join
     #bar b
     on f.name = b.name;
```

With the right indexes, this would be faster.

Comment: the first assumption is right, but I do need the rows that occure in only #foo or #bar to appear also. I forgot to put in an expected result, will do so now.

Comment: @Steef . . . Hence the first answer.

Comment: You are right, in all hectic I did not read properly. The first answer does the trick, I am going to do some tests with it. Out of pure curiosity I'll keep the answer open for a little while, hoping people come up with more suggestions, so I can learn.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the above from Gordon, the tables need to have indexes to prevent unnecessary performance issues.

My answer would be the following:

```
DECLARE @FOO TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(5), Occures INT)
DECLARE @BAR TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR(5), Occures INT)

INSERT INTO @FOO(FirstName,Occures) VALUES
('a',1)
,('b',2)
,('c',3)
,('d',4)

INSERT INTO @BAR(FirstName,Occures) VALUES
('c',1)
,('d',2)
,('g',3)
,('h',4)


DECLARE @SearchName VARCHAR(5) = 'D'

SELECT   COALESCE(B.FirstName, F.FirstName) AS FirstName
        ,SUM(ISNULL(B.Occures, 0) + ISNULL(F.Occures, 0)) AS TotalOccures
FROM @FOO F
    FULL OUTER JOIN @BAR B ON B.FirstName = F.FirstName
WHERE 1=1
    AND (B.FirstName = @SearchName OR F.FirstName = @SearchName)
GROUP BY
        B.FirstName
        ,F.FirstName
```

I've used temp tables in the example, but you could use real/temp tables. But if you're using the above in a real-world query I would avoid #temp tables unless absolutely necessary, again, for performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly a repeat of existing answers

A primary key should help

The first was 1/2 the cost of the second
Without the order by the cost is the same

```
declare @foo table (FirstName varchar(500) primary key, Occures int);
declare @bar table (FirstName varchar(500) primary key, Occures int);
 insert into @foo values
    ('a', 1) 
  , ('c', 3)
  , ('b', 2)
  , ('d', 4);
 insert into @bar values
    ('c', 1)
  , ('g', 3)
  , ('h', 4)
  , ('d', 2);


select FirstName, sum(Occures) as SumOccures 
from ( select FirstName, Occures from @foo 
       union all 
       select FirstName, Occures from @bar 
     ) tt
group by FirstName
order by FirstName 

select isnull([@foo].FirstName, [@bar].FirstName)
     , sum(isnull([@foo].Occures, 0) + isnull([@bar].Occures, 0)) as SumOccures
from @foo 
full outer join @bar 
  on [@foo].FirstName = [@bar].FirstName 
group by [@foo].FirstName, [@bar].FirstName  
order by isnull([@foo].FirstName, [@bar].FirstName)
```